# mactex 2015 : xindy doesn't find module

Tags: mactex, xindy

since I was moving from MacTeX 2014 to MacTeX 2015, xindy is not able to find any module. Any

`texindy -L english   -C utf8 animal.idx`

makes

> Cannot locate xindy module for language english in codepage utf8

Changing language and/or input don't change anything.

I have reinstalled all mactex, and now it works. But why didn't ? the mystery still remains.

However, after a tlmgr update --all, it does not work again.

It seems 1/1, ??:??/??:??] update: xindy [534k] (37078 -> 37716) was at the origin of the problem.

Here is the .idx file I tried

`\indexentry{chat!sauvage}{1}
\indexentry{chat!domestique}{1}
\indexentry{tortue!marine}{1}
\indexentry{tortue!terrestre}{1}
\indexentry{élèphant!d'Asie}{1}
\indexentry{élèphant!d'Afrique}{1}
\indexentry{élan!de Sibérie}{1}
\indexentry{élan!d'Amérique}{1}
\indexentry{chat!sauvage}{2}
\indexentry{chat!domestique}{2}
\indexentry{tortue!marine}{2}
\indexentry{tortue!terrestre}{2}
\indexentry{élèphant!d'Asie}{2}
\indexentry{élèphant!d'Afrique}{2}
\indexentry{élan!de Sibérie}{2}
\indexentry{élan!d'Amérique}{2}
\indexentry{chat!sauvage}{3}
\indexentry{chien!errant}{3}`

Comment: have you tried `xindy -M texindy ....` instead of `texindy`

Comment: same problem...

Comment: Questions: Do you only have MacTeX 2015 installed or did you install it alongside 2014? What does `which xindy` or `which texindy` give? What does `echo $PATH` return? Have you checked the MacTeX preferences in System Preferences to ensure that the 2015 version is properly enabled? Does `/usr/texbin` exist? If so, what does `ls -l /usr/texbin` give? Does `/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/*/texindy` exist?

Comment: a) I had MacTeX 2014 in the past, but now, I have only 2015. Because I have suppressed /usr/local/texlive/2014/ one month ago (but I didn't test xindy between installation of 2015 and deletion of 2014)

Comment: b)  texlive preference reference to the only installation : 2015 c) which xindy /Library/TeX/texbin/xindy (/Library/TeX/texbin/texindy) d) echo $PATH return /usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/texbin

Comment: ls -l /usr/texbin : lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  63 14 jui 22:37 /usr/texbin -> /Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin /usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/*/texindy exist

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been solved by a software update

Comment: no, just two minutes. I have made new test.

Comment: with reinstall. it works. but with update of xindy 37078 -> 37716) it does not work again.

Comment: Of course I get `Could not find file "philologue.xdy"`; can you make a real MWE?

Comment: oh, the problem is the same without the -M  philologue.xdy"Cannot locate xindy module for language english in codepage utf8"

Comment: @Maïeul Not on my machine (where I have 37716)

Comment: strange, it seems that is my installation, but where? coming back to 37078 make all thing working

Comment: @Maïeul : Thanks for your report.  The xindy.pl in the TeX Live is updated (38098),
which will be available soon in TeX Live 2015.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto, I'm assuming that update will be available on all systems? As far as I can see it is caused by some quotes in the wrong place?

Comment: @daleif: Yes on all systems. Yes you are right.